# Python 2.7 and MySQL: grooming tuple

Tags: python, mysql

I am self-taught in MySQL, Python and Linux based OS, and quite sure there must be a more elegant solution to the problem, or, at least, one that works along my lines. 
The code is taking data from the last 24 hours from a database and storing them to a .txt file to be handled further on. However, the output I am getting has additional symbols that are making further analysis troublesome - I want to know if there is a way to remove them.

My (relevant) code is:

```
    ...
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Sens WHERE sdate > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR)")
    query = cur.fetchall()

    OutputFile = open("/root/Desktop/data.txt", "w")
    for i in range (0, len(query)):
        print>>OutputFile, query[i]
    ...
```

The reason I am using for loop is to have each row fetched printed in a newline. 
The result I get is as follows:

```
    ('0,01/24/16,12:41:49,45.185\r\r\n',)
```

The result I need is:

```
    0,01/24/16,12:41:49,45.185
```

Much appreciate the help,
LZ.

Comment: As i see the results are a tuple first try `query[i][0]` and if there are still some  chars left you can use `re` to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, you shouldn't ever be iterating over `range(len(something))`. Always iterate over the thing itself. Also, it's more idiomatic to use `file.write` to output, rather than pritnting.

From there, all you need to do is just output the first element in each item, with `[0]`.

```
for q in query:
   OutputFile.write(q[0])
```

Comment: I am always looking for quality programming tips, so thank you for them! Should I make q then a variable of the size of the length of query? like 
`q = len(query)`

Comment: No, the whole point is that there is no need to get the length of the query. Just iterate over it.

Comment: wow - i did not know that was even possible. yes, that works perfectly - thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
for i in range (0, len(query)):
        print>>OutputFile, query[i][0].strip()
```

The `[0]` index selects the string from the tuple, and the `strip()` function removes the whitespace from the left and right hand side of the string.